# LPEG - "Rule may be left-recursive" error, despite being a terminable grammar

Tags: preprocessor, left-recursion, lpeg

I'm trying to use LPEG to build a preprocessor for GLSL. I've managed to get #define and #undef statements working no problem, but my issues comes when trying to work with #ifdef statements.

My thought was that I could build a rule that would encapsulate a shader, bordered by #ifdef and #endif statements, like so:

```
S -> include | define | ifdef | code
ifdef -> "#ifdef" + var + S + "#endif"
```

Clearly this grammar is terminable, as the ifdef rule requires capturing #ifdef and the macro name before the recursive call. However, LPEG disagrees, claiming this rule "may be left recursive".

Does anyone know what I can do about this?

Thanks.

Comment: You definitely need to add definitions for `include`, `define`, `code` and `var`. Especially `var`.

Comment: I thought it was obvious these had definitions set up. The error would be different otherwise. Regardless this has long since been solved. So long ago that I don't even remember the solution.

Comment: I meant that you needed to add those definitions to your question. I am glad that you have solved your problem.